# How to change the default height of bottomsheet dialog fragment?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

While using bottomsheet dialog fragment it set default height for bottomsheet dialog. In my application I want to set 80% height for bottomsheet dialog. How can I set 80% height to bottomsheet dialog?

Comment: show your work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this following code.

```
super.setupDialog(dialog, style);

View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_device_nfclocation, null);

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

int maxHeight = (int) (height*0.88);

BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) contentView.getParent());
mBehavior.setPeekHeight(maxHeight);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do this  it works replace 600dp by any height you need

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   
    
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>
    
</style>


<style name="CustomBottomSheet" 
    parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
         <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">

    <item name="behavior_peekHeight">600dp</item>
</style>
```